# Remove rows with NAs for matrices in a list

Tags: r, list, matrix, na

I recognize that this question could be a duplicate.

I have a list of matrices and for each matrix, I want to identify whether or not there is an NA present in the first column. I want to identify its position (the row) and remove that row if there is an NA present. I want to apply this operation to all matrices in a list.

```
mat1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow =2, ncol =2, data = c(NA, 0,0,1)))
mat2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow =2, ncol =5, data = c(0,0,1,2,1,NA,1,1,1,1)))
mat3 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow =3, ncol =2, data = c(NA, 0,0,1,NA,1)))

list <- list(mat1,mat2,mat3)

lapply(list, function(x) !is.na(x[,1]))
```

I want the output to be stored in an equivalent list(say list2). for example list2[[1]] would be a 1x2 matrix. list2[[2]] would be a 1x5 matrix. and list 2[[3]] would be a 1x2 matrix (only keeping rows without NA in column 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is only for the first column, we loop through the `list` with `lapply`, then use an. anonymous function call, get the first column (`x[,1]`), check the `NA` with (`is.na`), negate (`!`) i.e. for non_NA elemengts and subset the rows of the dataset based. on that

```
list2 <- lapply(list, function(x) x[!is.na(x[,1]),, drop = FALSE])
```

---

For the entire dataset in the `list`, we can make use of `rowSums` on the logical matrix created with `is.na` on the entire dataset.

```
lapply(list, function(x) x[rowSums(is.na(x)) == 0,, drop = FALSE])
```